# Cannot see pictures on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, images, imgur

When I upload an image to Stack Overflow, I cannot see my JPEG file in my post. It's all blank. I've tried it with different files, but gotten the same result.

Comment: Can you post links to the questions or answers that are having problems?

Comment: Can you try with a different image format, like GIF?

Comment: [Original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703485/issue-with-css-inherit-and-ajax), but it uses a different host (I can see image just fine). You can also try uploading right here at Meta (edit your question), it uses the same API.

Comment: For answers about `i.stack.imgur.com` see [Is there any work-around if you are somewhere where images are blocked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209161/is-there-any-work-around-if-you-are-somewhere-where-images-are-blocked).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see the images just fine in your post.

Could imgur.com be blocked at your workplace?

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

Comment: You're right Jeff. After what you mentioned, I noticed that we can view, create, or edit posts in StackOverFlow, but we cannot upload any snapshot. I just asked them to unblock it. Thanks for the support.

Comment: You are lucky. In Turkey, `imgurl` is banned country-wide.

Answer (score 7):

When [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) is blocked, then to at least be able to view images **that were uploaded before May 2011, and hence were using the regular `imgur.com` domain, not the specific `stack.imgur.com` domain**:

- See [fretje's userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83256/my-link-not-visible-to-me/83275#83275) to replace it with the alternative [filmot.com](http://filmot.com) domain (a proxy).
- Or, for these very Stack Exchange sites (or any other site where jQuery is available), the following quick & dirty script can be used as [a bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), or can simply be pasted into the location bar (just like an address/URL) after a page has loaded:

  > javascript:function r(i,v){return v===undefined?v:v.replace(/(\w*.?)imgur.com/i,'$1filmot.com');}$('a').attr('href',r);$('img').attr('src',r);

**Beware**: filmot.com [is not affiliated](http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/alch6/please_use_imgurcom_to_share_images_instead_of/c0i7cc5) with Imgur; I would NOT recommend signing in through that mirror but to always use imgur.com to access your private account, if applicable. Also, if you are *very* sensitive about your privacy, you might not want to use it?

It seems there's also an official imgur.com alternative domain, [imgur.voxcdn.com](http://imgur.voxcdn.com/YzHzE.jpg). But that uses [the very same IP addresses](http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/alch6/please_use_imgurcom_to_share_images_instead_of/c0ifl8i) so is probably blocked too.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `imgur.com` was blocked by the company server/firewall and not the chrome so in this case it should be unblocked by the server admin. To check whether your company is blocking causing the images not display on StackOverflow etc just try to navigate to `imgur.com` website and you should be able to see if the company is blocking it or not