# What should be done with questions containing Dropbox image links?

Tags: discussion, edits, images

Occasionally I run into questions that have an image link hosted on Dropbox. My initial instinct is to edit the question and rehost the image @ imgur, but in the case where the user who asked the question likes to modify the image, he would expect that he wouldn't need to make any change to his question, and wouldn't understand (or even notice) why the image was not updated.

What then should be done about images hosted on Dropbox or similar sites?

Comment: a simple comment explaining what you did with the image and why would leave no room for confusion :-)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75962/is-it-ok-to-save-and-re-upload-images-in-questions

Comment: @random That's indeed related, but my answer would be far more firm than Jeff's. Just do it. Is there any reason to suggest otherwise?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit the question to host the image on whatever the standard host is (http://stack.imgur.com/ in our case). Hosting image files on Dropbox makes the post un-maintainable. There is no guarantee that the image will keep existing and as a result the whole post might become invalid or at least incomplete.

In the worst case, should the OP not notice his question got edited, you could leave a comment stating so and explaining why you did it.

Comment: Don't people get ping-notified when a post of theirs is revised?  Wouldn't the poster see the edit history comment and thereby eliminating the need for an additional comment?

Comment: @jmort253 yes we do, a friend (_ahem_) of a friend that writes low quality posts and have them constantly edited, once told me that we do get a notification.

Comment: If you want a textbook example of what can go wrong when you host images on Dropbox, look at the revision history for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2183287/revisions . They were using the default screenshot link in their Dropbox account, and it must have been overridden at some point.

Comment: @jmort253 Yeah, they do get notified, but who knows what people overlook....

Comment: @BradLarson - That is hilarious, and a good reason to just upload your images and not rely on the third-party!