# All Imgur accounts are "Pro" nowadays: should we still move regular Imgur uploads to the Stack Exchange account?

Tags: discussion, images, imgur, link-rot

In [August 2010](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/), Stack Exchange started providing user uploads to an Imgur Pro account:

> Alan Schaaf, the man behind Imgur, generously provided us a network-wide "pro" account that keeps any images hosted through our websites around indefinitely.

At that time, uploads to free accounts would expire at some point. But I just learned that since February 9th, 2015 [all accounts are "Pro"](https://imgur.com/blog/2015/02/09/imgur-pro-for-everyone/):

> We’re phasing out Pro subscriptions...and making the Pro features completely free for every Imgur user!

I am not 100% sure this also applies to anonymous uploads, but [their Help now says](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/201476457-How-long-do-you-keep-the-images-):

> **How long do you keep the images?**
>   Sarah Schaaf - February 16, 2015 22:23
>
> Forever! An image is only removed if deletion is requested.

Though some explicitly [want to be able to control their uploads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75962/is-it-ok-to-save-and-re-upload-images-in-questions/75971#75971), I guess chances are low that an uploader requests deletion. But Waffles [commented in May 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com/94286#comment225068_90342), when the `i.stack.imgur.com` URLs were introduced:

> we are in the process of migrating to new dedicated image servers which we will back up regularly. Once this is complete we will announce. [...] Our main goal here is to have local backups of images you folk upload and dedicated servers

So:

When editing, should we still move images from `i.imgur.com` to the Stack Exchange account? (By using the *"provide a link from the web"* option from the Ctrl+G image upload dialog.)

Comment: Do you mean, if we happen to notice that an image is hosted on imgur, should we still use the "provide a link from the web" option? I don't usually pay attention to where an image is hosted when I add images to posts... maybe I'm simply not understanding what you're asking?

Comment: Indeed, @Catija, when I'm already editing and notice it's a regular Imgur upload (or a totally different provider), then I use that option.

Comment: @Arjan yes we should migrate them to i.stack.imgur.com. This is because SE use the API to keep track of their uploads etc.