# Browse button in Image insertion doesn't work in IE7

Tags: bug, images, editor, imgur

When I try to add an image to a question or answer, I'm not able to browse my local files in IE7. When I push the "Browse" button it looks like the "Upload" button gets focus. But nothing else happens.

[image: Odd focus of Browse button]

Comment: Works fine here; are you seeing any JavaScript errors?

Comment: @balpha: No I don't see any errors. My IE version is 7.0.6002.18005CO.

Comment: +1, the SE provided Imgur pro account is important to [prevent image rot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75815/what-smart-ways-to-prevent-image-rot-can-we-come-up-with)!

Comment: I no longer have IE7, but this looks exactly like what I remember seeing.

Comment: IE7 is no longer support, so I'm voting to close this as too localized.