# Recognize Imgur URLs when inserting an image

Tags: feature-request, images, imgur

The insert image feature does not recognize images that are already hosted on [Imgur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur), so when you try to use the toolbar to insert one of these, it gets duplicated on their website.

For example, I took a snapshot of a question and pushed it directly to Imgur.  I got my URL here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOuTn.png

Now, if I click the toolbar button, select "from the web", and paste the URL in, it (or Imgur or somebody does this, I'm not sure) re-uploads the image to the host.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiuEl.png

If the insert-image function of the editor was to simply recognize the domain of the URL as Imgur, this double-upload could be avoided.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> it gets duplicated on their website

No, it gets copied and hence *secured* to the SE [pro account](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/), from which images will never expire. That's much better to prevent [image rot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75815/what-smart-ways-to-prevent-image-rot-can-we-come-up-with)!

(It would be great if we could somehow see which images are on the SE account, and which are not.)

Comment: That true?  If it is, then I guess it's perfectly acceptable, and I should probably change my workflow.  Anybody know how to take a screenshot using javascript?  Derp.

Comment: @Will, since May 2011, images uploaded to the SE pro account use the `stack.imgur.com` domain so you can see for yourself ;-)