# Please add special-case code for the "image" button when the image is already on imgur

Tags: feature-request

I saw the following edit suggestion today:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/179914

The original poster included an image with URL `https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeZRb.jpg` but didn't use the proper formatting to inline the image because his reputation is too low.

A helpful editor hit the "image" button in the editor and pasted in the URL, and *probably* the imgur-uploader tool dutifully downloaded and then re-uploaded the image to imgur.

I've seen this behavior when editing posts myself but just worked around it by typing the Markdown manually.

I'd like to suggest that the "image upload" button on the toolbar simply add the formatting around the input URL if the input URL is already on `i.stack.imgur.com`. This change would make reviewing suggested edits easier.

Comment: That was me... sorry?  :)

Comment: @Marvin: hooray! You can tell me if I guessed the sequence of events correctly. :) I'd like to make the edits you just made far easier as I've gotten a bit tired of hand-inserting the markdown code. (I know, I'm lazy. It doesn't even come up very often...)

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I did. I've never inserted an image into a post before so the most logical thing (for me) was click that little `image` button and if I remember correctly, one option was along the lines of `From the Internet`, which I chose and pasted in the imgur URL.

Comment: @Marvin: excellent, thanks for the confirmation, I just took out _two_ "probably" statements, which is always a good improvement. :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79378/recognize-imgur-urls-when-inserting-an-image