# Support Imgur URLs that aren't the image source

Tags: feature-request, images, imgur

Currently, if you insert an imgur URL like this:

```
http://imgur.com/C5o9sLE
```

it says it can't do anything:

[image]

So I have to manually change the url to this:

```
http://i.imgur.com/C5o9sLE.png
```

which is annoying. Please could the image uploader auto change `imgur.com/*` to `i.imgur.com/*.png`?

Comment: Note that this question [Recognize Imgur URLs when inserting an image](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79378/recognize-imgur-urls-when-inserting-an-image) is asking for a different reason and it's on the old uploader. Also that was nearly 5 years ago.