# My link not visible to me

Tags: support, images

Hello..
Today i posted a question in stackoverflow
[here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310956/how-to-put-images-at-exact-location-dynamically)

I uploaded a image from my desktop and from a comment of a user it seems that he is able to view that image but I was not able to see that link in my preview of question neither in actual question. Here is screenshot of what i see. [image: click]

again while pasting the screenshot I am not able to see it in preview.

Comment: I'm noticing that you have a giant whitespace where the top-banner ad should go. Perhaps, do you have some sort of image blocking service that might be affecting the site imgur.com?

Comment: are you able to see the image of a shelf that i have uploaded in stackoverflow?? I am not able to see it myself at all..

Comment: yes there is blocking system. I am not able to access imgur.com

Comment: Same problem here... imgur is blocked by our websense :-s

Comment: This might help you and @fretje then: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249/images-hosted-in-imgur-com

Comment: Another option is to upload the image to any other image hosting website yourself then instead of Browsing to the image, post its URL.

Comment: [Objection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75815/what-smart-ways-to-prevent-image-rot-can-we-come-up-with) to not using the future proof SE provided image hosting, @Shadow and all!

Comment: @Arjan problem is that many work places block `imgur` - so while future proof it's not workplace proof. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are blocking imgur - as indicated by your comment - then you will not be able to see the images uploaded as they are hosted by imgur.

If you are in control of the system then consider unblocking it.

If you aren't then you will have to make a **very** good case to your IT department on why it should be unblocked.

Comment: ok.. but then why i was not able to see that in preview as a hyperlink as i was able to see the hyperlink for "here is the link" in my question. Is it the same reason for that?

Comment: @Harshad - I'm not sure I understand what you are getting at here, but the image is only displayed in the preview once it's been uploaded to imgur, so if you are blocking imgur it won't be shown.

Comment: i got that ill not be able to see the image preview simply because the image did not got fetched from imgur.com. that is fine now.. what I am asking now is when it ask you to enter image description and you type something then that should appear in preview as you type right??
but it isn't.

Comment: @Harshad, in the question you entered "click" as the description (which is not a very good one). This is used for the `alt` text. Some browsers do indeed show that if loading the image fails. Some don't, some show a broken image icon. Maybe in your case the actual image is replaced by a white image, so the browser doesn't *know* it's not getting the real image?

Comment: As you said i wrote click as description I was not able to see that description anywhere in my post as you are able to see it.Perhaps Its better i go home and check how it actually works when there is no restriction or blocking of sites. :P

Comment: I do not see it either, @Harshad, unless I edit your question, or unless I view the HTML source of this very page. (Of course, I do see the image instead.) Browsers do NOT normally show it. Whether or not it's shown when an image cannot be loaded, depends on the browser. (Note that the same `alt` text is used for screen readers, as used by visually impaired. Those users won't be helped by "click"!)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a userscript which changes all the imgur links to filmot links (an imgur mirror). Thanks to @Shadow Wizard to point me to this thing. It only worked on reddit though and only processed anchors, no image tags. I've updated it to also include this, and now I can see images again on stackexchange sites!

I also put it on [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/99047) for an easy install.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          imgur filmot
// @namespace     reddit, SOIS
// @description   Changes imgur.com links to filmot.com
// @include       http://reddit.com/*
// @include       http://www.reddit.com/*
// @include       http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://superuser.com/*
// @include       http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @include       http://serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include       http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include       http://nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http://meta.nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http://seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http://meta.seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http://crossvalidated.com/*
// @include       http://meta.crossvalidated.com/*
// @include       http://askdifferent.com/*
// @include       http://meta.askdifferent.com/*
// @include       http://stackapps.com/*
// @include       http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://api.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://area51.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://*/reputation
// ==/UserScript==

var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i) {
    var a = anchors[i];
    if (a.href && a.href.indexOf('http://imgur.com/') == 0) {
        a.href = a.href.replace('http://imgur.com/', 'http://filmot.com/');
    }
    if (a.href && a.href.indexOf('https://i.stack.imgur.com/') == 0) {
        a.href = a.href.replace('https://i.stack.imgur.com/', 'http://i.filmot.com/');
    }
}
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; ++i) {
    var img = imgs[i];
    if (img.src && img.src.indexOf('http://imgur.com/') == 0) {
        img.src = img.src.replace('http://imgur.com/', 'http://filmot.com/');
    }
    if (img.src && img.src.indexOf('https://i.stack.imgur.com/') == 0) {
        img.src = img.src.replace('https://i.stack.imgur.com/', 'http://i.filmot.com/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, glad to lend a hand! And @Arjan - guess this is ideal solution, as images will still be hosted on the future proof host.

Comment: Nice! Alternatively, as a quick & dirty bookmarklet when knowing jQuery has been loaded (like on the Stack Exchange sites): `javascript:function r(i,v){return v===undefined?v:v.replace(/(\w*\.?)imgur\.com/i,'$1filmot.com');}$('a').attr('href',r);$('img').attr('src',r);`

Comment: It seems there's also an official imgur.com alternative domain, [imgur.voxcdn.com](http://imgur.voxcdn.com/YzHzE.jpg). But that uses [the very same IP addresses](http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/alch6/please_use_imgurcom_to_share_images_instead_of/c0ifl8i) so is probably blocked too. (@Sha)

Comment: Since May 2011, images uploaded to the SE pro account use the `stack.imgur.com` domain (and hence `i.stack.imgur.com` and maybe even more). The `filmot.com` proxy does not support that. See also [Any details about stack.imgur.com?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com)

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work anymore.  :(

Comment: This might still work using `i.stack.imgur.com.prx2.unblocksit.es`, like [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com.prx2.unblocksit.es/tfSdv.png), but that would first need a cookie by clicking "Unblock" on http://unblocksit.es/unblock/imgur.com