# Any details about stack.imgur.com?

Tags: discussion, images, imgur

Since May 2011, images uploaded through SE sites are uploaded to [`stack.imgur.com`](http://stack.imgur.com/). It seems that removing that `stack` part does not get one ([the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89734/mysterious-butt)) image, so it seems to be a standalone installation? Any details on that new domain? And: any new way to circumvent blocks of `imgur.com`?

And this nicely shows folks [are kind of abusing](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/I-got-problem-in-insert-non-english-to-form-td4378257.html) the SE image upload... But when using the data dump, can one also refer to the images from the SE hosting?

Like https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfSdv.png works fine:

[image]

But when removing `stack`, [http://i.imgur.com/tfSdv.png](https://i.imgur.com/tfSdv.png) (currently) does not refer to an image:

[image]

Also Imgur's firewall/proxy/blocking circumventing alternative domain http://imgur.voxcdn.com/tfSdv.png does not work, and neither does http://stack.imgur.voxcdn.com/tfSdv.png:

http://imgur.voxcdn.com/tfSdv.png http://stack.imgur.voxcdn.com/tfSdv.png

And of course [the non-official filmot.com](http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/alch6/please_use_imgurcom_to_share_images_instead_of/c0i7cc5) proxy doesn't know the new SE images either.

Likewise, existing images such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPYaC.png <s>do not</s> did not work when adding `stack` to it, https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB5JX.png:

[image] [image]

Comment: Nice mole-bunny! Maybe commenting [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) will get proper attention?

Comment: Good point, @Shadow, done. I first wanted to use an image from http://iwdrm.tumblr.com/ but couldn't easily find anything about copyrights there. :-)

Comment: Cheers @Arjan.. my guess is that StackExchange upgraded the account somehow, but can't find anything about it.. :/

Comment: Any 10k who can search SO for `url:"http://stack.imgur.com/H2mRB.jpg"`? Wondering why all hits I get in Google refer to non-SE sites. It's some CakePHP question, posted (or scraped and copied) all over the internets, using an image hosted on the SE pro account.

Comment: Not much to add here, we are in the process of migrating to new dedicated image servers which we will back up regularly. Once this is complete we will announce. As to having a diff domain name, we could discuss with Alan, but have not discussed yet. Our main goal here is to have local backups of images you folk upload and dedicated servers

Comment: Fun fact: the official [i.imgur.com/not-here.png](http://i.imgur.com/not-here.png) shows a different 404 image than the SE [i.stack.imgur.com/not-here.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/not-here.png) The first even [serves a GIF](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2Fnot-here.png&http=1.1&gzip=yes&type=GET&uak=0) rather than a PNG.

Comment: I thing you should get a badge on meta for abusing stack.imgur.

Comment: is stack.imgur down? I can't upload images... Maybe it is just me? I tried to upload multiple images and got denied. Can't upload now at all.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

We engaged in a 1 year agreement to formally support imgur, which also involved us getting

- a dedicated server on premises with them
- a custom domain name

All our images should be accessible from both forms of the URL now, either `i.imgur.com` or `i.stack.imgur.com` .. such as:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPYaC.png

and

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB5JX.png

Please note that we [retroactively replaced all forms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying/95734#95734) of `i.imgur.com` on the network from Aug 17 2010 onward, as a one time fix.

Comment: So when 1 year is up... then what happens?

Comment: The first one (http://i.imgur.com/VB5JX.png) is broken now.

Comment: Yep images there expire after couple of months. :)

Comment: on (at least) gis.se the `i.stack.imgr.com` domain is not interchangeable with `i.imgur.com`. See http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/664/what-happened-to-old-images

Comment: How much did that cost?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, see [Is stack.imgur.com hosting still free for Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213547/is-stack-imgur-com-hosting-still-free-for-stack-exchange)