# Broken images in "Remove new user restrictions"

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, broken-link

When my new user restrictions were removed, I saw [a privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) with a short tutorial on how to embed links and pictures in questions. The following example pictures were broken:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSZui.png
("insert link toolbar button"),

and,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3zkF.png
("insert image toolbar button").

Answer (score 4):

Somehow `stack` was inserted into the existing URLs of images that were uploaded before May 2011:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSZui.png versus https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSZui.png

[image] [image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3zkF.png versus https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3zkF.png

[image] [image]

It seems only https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user still refers to the correct image URLs. Might be a temporary problem though, while images are moved to [the new Stack Exchange specific Imgur domain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com).

Comment: As an aside: when Imgur URLs are not found, a 301 Moved Permanently to the 404 image is sent to the browser. Just refreshing the page will then not show the image *if* it eventually becomes available. A forced reload using something like Ctrl-Shift-R, or simply clearing your browser's cache, might be needed then.

Comment: btw, we can edit those pages on meta, but not on SO

Comment: @YOU, I thought Meta was used as the base for the others, but I once fixed some typo which did not survive later edits though ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.