# Add ability to post images to "Remove new user restrictions" privilege page

Tags: feature-request, privileges, images, help-center

I was looking for a note on when the ability to post images (inline) is unlocked in [the privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), but couldn't find any reference to it.

I assume it's unlocked at 10 reputation, and should be included in ["Remove New User Restrictions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user).

Can we add this in?

As an initial draft... (feel free to suggest something better)

Perhaps to "New users cannot", add:

> - Post images

And change the description of the privilege (seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)) from:

> Post more links, answer protected questions

to:

> Post images, more links, answer protected questions

---

It seemingly [was there before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90602/broken-images-in-remove-new-user-restrictions):

> I saw a privileges page with a short tutorial on how to embed links **and pictures** in questions.

Was it removed for a specific reason?

---

If this is not directly linked to the  "Remove new user restrictions" privilege (i.e. it might have a different reputation requirement on another site), can we perhaps add a separate privilege for this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the ability to post images has different reputation thresholds on different sites, so on some sites you can post them even with 1 reputation.

Comment: Related: [Which SE sites require 10 reputation points to post images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258875/335251)

Comment: Related/duplicate: ['Remove New User Restrictions' privilege also allows uploading images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229543/335251)

Answer (score 3):

> Was it removed for a specific reason?

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/188688), the text about the restriction was removed because the restriction itself was removed, except for StackOverflow.

Comment: Fair enough, although, as long as it's on [so] and some other sites, it makes sense to have a note about it on the privileges page, at least in my opinion. I believe there is some variation in what the privileges page looks like on different sites (even if it's just the reputation varying), so I can't imagine that having a flag to display this (so it's only displayed on sites where the restriction exists) would be that much work.