# 'Remove New User Restrictions' privilege also allows uploading images?

Tags: discussion, privileges, images, help-center, help-center-proposed

An [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/252674) to the '[How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)' thread says that in order to do this you'll need the 'Remove New User Restrictions' privilege to do so.

The ['Remove New User Restrictions' page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) doesn't mention that, though.

So if that's the case, the page should explicitly say so.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Add ability to post images to "Remove new user restrictions" privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225689/335251)

Answer (score 7):

> Note you need to be registered member in the site with at least 10 reputation in order to gain the privilege to use this feature.

Actually they have [given the privilege of adding images to new users as well as anonymous users.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/233367)

> The privilege wiki has been updated to remove any mention of images in
>   the "remove new user restrictions" privilege.

So they removed this in  [Remove New User Restrictions page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user).  Unfortunately this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/233367) was not updated.

Know I have updated it.

Comment: As of the answer there the restriction is still there on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Ask Ubuntu and Super User. Shouldn't that be mentioned on the wiki page?

Comment: @SebastianZartner Actually we can post images as anonymous user in stackoverflow.  Also I check other sites help page, they have uplifted this restriction.

Comment: Hmm, then I wonder why in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049829/php-curl-request-changes-post-data hkjhj said that he doesn't have enough reputation to upload an image.