# Add link for image upload on mobile devices?

Tags: feature-request, images, link-rot

On devices that are not shown the editing toolbar, would it be possible to add some way to use [the SE provided imgur image upload](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post/75498#75498)?

(I appreciate [the effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com#comment-225068) SE has made to prevent image rot!)

Comment: Now that the iOS 6 beta supports image upload <which I can confirm does work>, this seems a lot more relevant.

Comment: Somebody better prevent awesome feature-request rot...