# Upload images from the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, images

I would like to request implementation of uploading images to questions/answers from the Stack Exchange Android app, especially now as it would **definitely help** uploading screenshots for reporting bugs and feature requests.

Comment: kind people who are using the web interface, please help tag appropriately as there isn't tag suggest or auto-complete on the app. thanks!

Comment: Please don't comment "Please also take a look at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a165483%20%5bandroid-app%5d" on every single thing you post. I've removed all of them; please don't re-add them.

Comment: Given that this is [not even implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153551/add-an-image-upload-button-to-the-mobile-site) [on the mobile version of the site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94725/add-link-for-image-upload-on-mobile-devices), I'm not sure how likely it is to get in the Android app. Certainly I'd rather see it added to the mobile site *first*, that way everyone can use it from their mobile device, including the very-neglected-feeling iOS folks.

Comment: If you just download a app off the market called ghost commander it's a app  to  move around files in your phone just go to your pic like that and upload it works just fine "Tex713"

Comment: @CodyGray No worries, iOS version is coming as well :) We just started with Android because it's much easier to quickly iterate versions in Google Play than in the App Store.

Comment: There hasn't been a large discussion of this feature as of yet.  Since it wasn't on the roadmap to V1.0.0 I wouldn't expect it until after that point.

Comment: Why was this status-deferred? Personally, this is a useful proposal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is implemented as of the newest beta release (1.0.52), if you're on the beta list check it out and let us know what you think, if you're not [join and help us test it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245731/help-us-test-the-stack-exchange-android-tablet-app).

[image]

Comment: Did you remove it at some point? Using version 1.0.60 and don't see such a thing when writing an answer, just the plain textarea.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, it just has a bug right now where it doesn't show until you start typing something in the message box.

Comment: Wow so simple! Is this android bug, or app bug? :)

Comment: Not working on my lg g3

Comment: @RuchirBaronia can you open a new post with more details and possibly a screenshot?