# Image upload from photo gallery

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, ios-app

So this is pretty obvious. Image upload?

[image: mock up with "paste" and "insert photo" buttons in context menu]

How about allowing to attach images in questions from the photo gallery, by perhaps sending the image for off-site storage like done from the full-web version?

Comment: I'm confused at what's being asked , can you clarify?

Comment: In the new iOS app, allow to attach images in questions by selecting an image from the iOS photos gallery - send it to storage like done in the full website and then add it in the question.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191537/upload-images-from-the-stack-exchange-android-app. I wouldn't expect it until around or after Android gets it.

Comment: But... image upload in iOS is *so easy*!

Comment: @BrianNickel Why would this need to wait for android? Direct iOS image upload works today on the web app (full site) so the back end and imgur are iOS ready from what I can tell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have implemented this recently. Feel free to test it and give us any feedback you may have.

[image: Stack Exchange iOS App Image uploading]

Comment: I didn't think bounties worked on SE developers. Careful about setting a precedent. **+50!**

Comment: This is great... Thanks :).

Comment: Doesn't work on android

Comment: @RuchirBaronia of course not, android app is totally different

Answer (score 2):

Magic!

[image]

Comment: I can't be held responsible for the app to remove any Moiré patterns ;)