# Allow me to paste images directly into the question body

Tags: feature-request, editor, ios-app, uploader

It'd be **extremely** handy if we were able to paste images directly into the post textarea (both from photos saved on my iPhone, and photos from other websites, if there's any difference).

I'd expect this action would upload the image to i.stack.imgur.com, and the markdown for the image inserted into the cursor position.

Currently, it's a bit of a faf to go to the full website view on a browser, upload the image, then return to the mobile app to insert the markdown yourself.

Comment: There is another a duplicate here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220342/image-upload-from-photo-gallery