# How to upload diagrams on iPhone 4s

Tags: support, mobile-web, uploader

I am currently using Stack Exchange using Safari on my iPhone 4s. How can I upload a diagram to this site from the camera roll?

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the mobile theme of Stack Exchange sites does not support image uploads, it got only the plain textbox editor without any buttons whatsoever.

There is a [pending feature request asking to add it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153551/add-an-image-upload-button-to-the-mobile-site), but it might take years, if at all, to be done.

Until then, you can switch to "full site" mode on the mobile device:

> [image]

Now you can just tap the image upload icon in the editor and upload same way you do it in a desktop computer.

Another option is upload the picture to a different site, e.g. imgur.com and using the raw markup:

```
![description](URL)
```

Or if you feel more comforable, raw HTML tag:

```
<img src="URL" />
```

Comment: Is that possible via iOS though?

Comment: @JonW this was [added a year ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220342/image-upload-from-photo-gallery)  - worth to mention android app doesn't have such feature yet. [This request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191537/upload-images-from-the-stack-exchange-android-app) appears as completed, but I now tried and it does not appear to work. :/

Comment: Android has the imgur app itself which allows uploading of images. Then it's a case of copy-pasting the URL into the post. Which is actually probably more long-winded that this iOS version, now that I think about it.