# Insert image from iOS Photo Roll

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

It would be very nice to be able to include images from an iOS device in a post (question, answer), etc.

I am testing the iOS app now and I had like to include some images, but it doesn't seem possible to do it now and since iOS is very willing to expose the images to the web I can't add it to imgur for example.

Comment: There is an imgur app for iOS is there not? If the Stack Exchange app can't handle uploading images then you should still be able to add to imgur from the app and link to it from there, I would presume anyway.

Comment: @JonW: didn't know that. But it seems very useful to integrate this with the app.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191537/upload-images-from-the-stack-exchange-android-app It's something we want to do but there's no real timeline for it.