# My Stack Overflow imgur images are disappearing

Tags: support, imgur

A while back I answered this question and used the official Stack Overflow image uploader:

> [Using ServerManager to create Application within Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518186)

I just noticed that some of the images I had in my answer seem to be no longer available from imgur and look like this:

[image]

These images use the original `i.imgur.com` url.

**Update:**

Just found this:

> [Any details about stack.imgur.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com)

There's also this post where Jeff also says to use `i.stack.imgur.com`:

> [The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1409)

This seems to work and the image I uploaded above uses `i.stack.imgur.com`.

Comment: That is strange. I see it too. Can you replace it with stack.imgur.com instead of i?

Comment: I've just updated the answer replacing `i.imgur` with `stack.imgur` and that seems to have done the trick. Perhaps a general trawl the database is called for.

Comment: There is a report about this on the TeX meta: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/the-image-you-are-requesting-does-not-exist-or-is-no-longer-available

Comment: @chrisf - yeah I just did that too :). Phew!

Comment: Possibly related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94959/missing-image-in-view-close-votes

Comment: @squillman no, that image is from twitpic.

Comment: @ChrisF that might not be a wise thing - I've been using imgur before Stack Exchange brought in the image uploader - updating i.imgur to stack.imgur might result in images uploaded to imgur before introduction of Stack Exchange's image uploader to go dead. Do correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Another user on EE complained about a missing image, but I could still see it.  I assumed that I just had it in my cache, so I saved and downloaded it, then re-uploaded it.  Conclusion: It bugs out for some users for some pictures, but isn't universal.  Steps to reproduce unknown.

Answer (score 12):

I have noticed the same thing. It started some time yesterday.

The workaround seems to be to replace

```
i.imgur.com
```

by

```
i.stack.imgur.com
```

I would fix the images in that question  of yours, but I'm scared of heights!

Comment: Ah ha! That's done the trick. When did this change happen?

Comment: [I fixed my broken imgurs by re-uploading instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5623150/revisions) Silly me...

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy / firewall / web filter?  If so, they could be blocking imgur.com.

Comment: No firewalls. However see Pekka's answer.