# Imgur images are (re)disappearing again

Tags: feature-request, support, status-planned, images, imgur

I've seen several of these, the last few days:
[image: AWOL image, image]
`"The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available."`

For example, see [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/92726/3).

So, searching, I found [this answer to "My Stack Overflow imgur images are disappearing"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94989/my-stack-overflow-imgur-images-are-disappearing/94991#94991).

There the solution is to replace `i.imgur.com` with `i.stack.imgur.com` in the image URL.
But, for [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/92726/3), the solution was the opposite, [to replace `i.stack.imgur.com` with `i.imgur.com`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/92726/4).

Was some sweep done through the DB, replacing all `i.imgur.com` with `i.stack.imgur.com`?
EDIT: Apparently [there is an ¿ongoing? sweep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying/95734#95734)

If so, maybe it busted some images?  (I recall seeing 3 or 4, in the last 2 days. Alas, I only captured details for the last one.)

---

### Feature/Support request:

How hard would it be for a job to:

1. Loop through all `i.stack.imgur.com` images (or at least the ones that were auto replaced from `i.imgur.com`, if possible).
2. If a request for the image returns `404`, try fetching with an `i.imgur.com` URL.
3. If the image is at `i.imgur.com`, restore the URL in the DB or transfer the image to the `i.stack.imgur.com` domain on the Imgur server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As part of a bigger project, we've done #1 and #2.  #3 is absolutely planned, we just haven't gotten to it yet.