# Is i.stack.imgur.com deleting images?

Tags: support, bug, images, imgur

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Images manually uploaded to Imgur are not displaying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying)

I thought that images uploaded to `i.stack.imgur.com` are supposed to remain permanently, but it seems some of them are getting deleted. The server returns a PNG image saying "The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available."

See [Mathematica: Transparent background with PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6326272/2) for an example.

This *might* be the same issue as [Imgur images are (re)disappearing again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101028/imgur-images-are-redisappearing-again).

A while ago, something like this happened transiently, where navigating to `http://i.imgur.com/[SAME PATH]` in the browser fixed the problem, so it was presumably a server-side cache issue. But that doesn't work for these images.

Comment: I wonder why we rely on an external service to do this. While not trivial, implementing an image uploader is not that difficult either. We're building a no-nonsense dependence on imgur and taking a big risk.. What happens if the site closes down?

Comment: It *does* work for these images, if you're referring to those embedded in the example question you linked. If it doesn't, then the image was deleted because it was inactive for 6 months.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: If they were manually uploaded to imgur, wouldn't the URLs be on `i.imgur.com` rather than `i.stack.imgur.com`?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Read [Jeff's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying/95734#95734) on that post

Comment: @Koper, we have processes in place that will allow us to recover should imgur disappear.