# Styles missed on the Edit Profile & Settings tab in most of the Stack Exchange sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

In most of the Stack Exchange site's **Edit Profile & Settings** tab, the menu items in the left hand side were loaded without the styles.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Styles not applied]

---

To visit the edit profile page, try the URL: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current

After inspect an elements, the CSS classes related to `#side-menu ul li` are missing.

Browser and OS details:

Mozilla Firefox: `54.0b10 (32-bit)`
Google Chrome: `Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)`
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Current MSE version is not relevant, instead please tell what browser you are using.

Comment: @Paweł planned usually means "OK, we know there's a bug, will fix it in 6-8 weeks" - hope that's not the case here? (i.e. it will be fixed sooner, e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101028/imgur-images-are-redisappearing-again) is planned for nearly 6 years(!)).

Comment: @ShadowWizard man, there's lots of planning behind that 6y old issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up! Sadly, we had two rendering paths; one for Stack Overflow and one for everything else. Eurgh. We've propagated the styling from SO to the rest of the network to eliminate that stinky tech debt and pushed it out the door. Things are looking a little better now.

Comment: So what you say is that Stack Overflow design overflowed to the rest of the network?

Comment: Are we missing the `>` symbol in the side menu as per this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORfdP.png)