# The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, imgur

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/200518/183921) has 3 images on the `i.stack.imgur.com` domain that are appearing like this:

[image]

This related question: [My Stack Overflow imgur images are disappearing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94989/my-stack-overflow-imgur-images-are-disappearing) has an answer by Pekka 웃, suggesting to change the URL from `i.imgur.com` to `i.stack.imgur.com`.

Here though, the opposite is true - changing from https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAPTu.png to https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4U9R.png finds the image.

Maybe it's worth pinging [Alan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75143/195862)?

Comment: Is it possible that the images were never uploaded to SE's imgur?

Comment: Argh. I really, really want to fix the broken image in your question body.

Answer (score 3):

The fix seems ... obvious. :) I edited the links and the images show up in the answer once again.

If you feel like uploading them to our Imgur account, go for it. The answer looks like it predates our arrangement with Imgur, although I'm admittedly a bit hazy on that timeline since it also predates most of my involvement with the network.

Comment: Roughly when http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

Comment: @random Well, there goes that theory.

Comment: There are quite a few questions on MSO about images disappearing from SE's Imgur account... albeit from a while ago. I don't think this should be `by-design`.