# Why was an answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

The question "[How to show pending changes only for the currently opened solution in Visual Studio 2010 (TFS) and not the complete list of all changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896899/how-to-show-pending-changes-only-for-the-currently-opened-solution-in-visual-stu)" has 23 upvotes and the answer with a whopping 31 upvotes was deleted by a mod.

Seems like a good answer to me - how can I find out why this answer was deleted?

Answer (score 5):

The moderator flag on the post says "Broken image link."  It must not have been working that day, and without the image, the answer is useless.  But it looks OK now.

I undeleted the answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Possibly related to this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184501/178816

Comment: Moderator flags work on deleted posts too.  If you don't want to bother writing a meta post next time, you can just cast a moderator flag with a custom explanation.

Comment: @TravisJ: The flag was cast six months ago.

Comment: So having a broken image is a valid reason for deletion? One would think you could at least search web.archive.org and re-upload it to stack's imgur

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: There are currently 200+ moderator flags in the queue, and roughly a thousand flags are cast every day.  On any given day, perhaps four out of the 12 volunteer moderators are actively engaging the site.  It takes a minute or so to evaluate each flag and... Well, I think you see where I'm going with this.

Comment: I think I see where you're going... we need a mod election soon?

Comment: @JoeFrambach No.  We regularly get the queue down to zero nowadays, which was unheard of before the most recent election.  But we don't spend several minutes researching every post. There are probably hundreds of users with enough reputation to do the kind of fine tuning that Richard describes.