# Is it allowed to use imgur uploader provided in SE/SO for legal things not used in SE/SO?

Tags: discussion, images, imgur

We know that images, that are uploaded by imgur image upload button in SE/SO, will not expire unless SE/SO changes the policy.

Is it allowed to use imgur uploader provided in SE/SO for legal things not used in SE/SO?
For example: We upload our own pictures to be used in our own blogs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [imgur service](http://imgur.com/) itself has nothing to do with Stack Exchange. Anyone who wants to use it to host/share images for their own purposes is free to do so.

In fact, that's exactly what the SE team did for a long time. It wasn't until recently that they [cut a deal with imgur](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com) to get a dedicated server and a custom sub-domain (`stack.imgur.com`).

So, I don't really understand why you would need or want to use the custom sub-domain when you could just use the regular imgur service like everyone else. It's completely free, and it should be just as reliable and stable as the custom `stack` sub-domain.

Comment: not exactly; our domain has an implied imgur "pro" account. Thus, usage of our domain would be .. the right word is not stealing, but something close to that ..

Comment: The advantage of abusing SE account is that the images never expire. For things like tech blogs, which may persist for years but might not have enough visitors this might be quite useful.