# Is there a way to get back the images I added using Stashbox in my Stack Overflow questions? 

Tags: support, questions, images

I added many images uploaded on [Stashbox](http://stashbox.org/) and used them in my many Stack Overflow questions.

Example:

- [Is it ok to use <strong> in place of <b> blindly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243074/is-it-ok-to-use-strong-in-place-of-b-blindly)

Images were helpful to make the question more understandable. Now Stashbox has closed down. Questions doesn't look good without those images.

Now even I don't remember what images I have added to which questions. Is there a way to get the images back?

Comment: Not really. I mean, if you don't have the images anymore, and they don't have the images anymore, who does?

Comment: Known risk of using free image hosting: they go down at some point. This is out of your hands, just remember to upload images properly in the future using the `imgur` hosting which *should* be up for long years to come.

Comment: How we can sure about imgur? is it ok to use Flickr?

Comment: @Jitendra StackExchange is paying imgur money to host the images, for one thing. Also, why would you even want to use another free host after this?

Comment: @lunboks - Ok I didn't know that Stackexchange paying money to imgur.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, `imgur` was down for about half day not long ago and it might get down at some point - but chances are much lower than free image host without real backbone.

Comment: @Shadow et al: SE is keeping their own copy. Or at least, waffles [commented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com#comment-225068): *Our main goal here is to have local backups of images you folk upload and dedicated servers.*

Comment: @Arjan hope you're right, didn't see him posting again since May - almost half year by now. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to get the images back - unless they decide to share the details of the S3 storage container after which you can download.

As @Shadow Wizard mentioned in the comments, use the inbuilt image uploader which uploads to `stack.imgur` account - these will remain forever since Stack Exchange maintains backup of the images

Comment: Seems like you have double posted. How did that happen...?

Comment: Huh, that's weird. I clicked on post an answer - nothing happened. Clicked on post again, was hit by captcha, entered and closed the tab - never bothered to check! @YiJiang's独角兽

Comment: Sounds like a bug, I remember the system won't allow exact duplicate after X minutes - unless you changed something when clicking again?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope, absolutely no changes were done

Answer (score 5):

In [What smart ways to prevent "image rot" can we come up with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75815/what-smart-ways-to-prevent-image-rot-can-we-come-up-with), sth [wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75815/what-smart-ways-to-prevent-image-rot-can-we-come-up-with/99241#99241):

> In August 2010 I fetched a copy of all images in posts on SO/SF/SU/META, based on the URLs found in the data dump (probably the one of July). [...] I still have all those images on disk, in case more are broken by now and somebody wants to start an effort to re-upload them somewhere or such.

If many users were using Stashbox, then maybe the team can somehow use this backup to upload them to Imgur after all?

If not, keep your fingers crossed that Stashbox lives up to [their June post](http://stashbox.org/news/2011/06/27/the-death-of-stashbox/) and then use the "from the web" option in the image upload dialog, to transfer a copy to Imgur:

> [...] we may mirror it on Amazon S3 so that users can grab anything they care about before it's gone forever.

and:

> We're working on ways to distribute files back to their owners. Stay tuned...

[image]

Comment: *If many users were using Stashbox* => There are only a handful of Stashbox images across the entire network.