# imgur.com is blocked at work because it is seen as an entertainment focus social media

Tags: discussion, imgur

[Since 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com), Stack Exchange use Imgur to handle pictures. If I personally have no problem with Imgur so far, some workplaces can have. Mine for example... Why a company would block it? Imgur is an online image sharing community and can be see as a complete social network like facebook, tumblr or twitter. Also, you can easily find NSFW content on Imgur...

I am not sure what could be a solution. Proxy, VPN, or else can be strictly forbidden. Two ideas:

### Use another DNS from Imgur

See with Imgur to use another url. For example, `https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB5JX.png` could be `http://i.stack.progur.com/VB5JX.png` or `http://i.stack.imgurpro.com/VB5JX.png`. This move the problem to the side of Imgur.

### Switch from Imgur to another solution

It could be self-hosted or another more "professional" hoster. I am sure that if you come to use Imgur that because they offers a lot of benefits. So not really a solution...

I welcome any other ideas.