# May we include reputation score in our professional profiles for employers?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At what point do you put your SO reputation in your resume?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/at-what-point-do-you-put-your-so-reputation-in-your-resume)

As the reputation score indicates the following:

- how much the community trusts you
- your communication skills
- the quality and relevancy of your questions and answers

May we include the link to our reputation to project our skills to employers? If yes, then what we can do to improve our reputation further?

Comment: See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/9948/285 - answers mention resumes as well as interviews

Comment: I find this to question to be more to-the-point than the other 'original' question that is linked to as a duplicate...  I would perhaps remove that final questions since, really, it deserves its own post (but check for existing ones first!)

Answer (score 3):

Given stackoverflow's moves in promoting careers.stackoverflow.com, I would think they would in fact *encourage* people to make their reputation, indeed their entire user profile, public when dealing with potential employers.

Now this is a big move towards increased online identity transparency.  As casperOne noted, users with 10K+ reputation can still see your deleted questions and answers.  First off they're not linked to from your profile, so they'd be tough to find, and *even if* they were, I would hope the very fact that you've deleted those posts is taken into account when checking a user's record on stackoverflow.  Also keep in mind potential employers can often find your profile on their own and poke around anyway.

In addition, this should **encourage better behavior** on stackoverflow because it emphasizes the fact that your stackoverflow user and its record is tied to your - pardon the acronym - 'irl' identity.  You should treat it as such.

Comment: *"users with 10K+ reputation can still see your deleted questions and answers"* - not directly linked from the profile though, they would have to stumble upon the posts somehow.

Comment: I did _not_ know that, thanks for the clarification.  I'll check out the 'dupe' post too.

Answer (score 1):

Can you?  Yes, but it might require attribution as per the [CC license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (kind of joking, kind of serious on this).

Even though rep is probably covered on the license, I think it would be a huge waste of StackExchange's resources to find all of the places on the Internet (and off) that a user's reputation is used and then somehow get them to *not* use it.

That said, I wouldn't worry about including it (without attribution) in your resume.

The question you *should* be asking is do you [*want to*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/at-what-point-do-you-put-your-so-reputation-in-your-resume) include your rep on your resume?  Is what you've contributed here on StackOverflow (or any StackExchange site for that matter) something that you believe is worth exposing to potential employers?

That's a question that only you can answer, given that *you* produced the content that you are referencing on your resume.

Also, be aware of the fact that 10K+ users can still see your deleted content (questions and answers), so if the person interviewing you decides that they want to dig deeper into your account, there's a possibility of them coming across something you don't want seen, even if you delete the content.

Comment: Wonder how people down vote and not explain by way of a comment.

Comment: @Kris: As [I've stated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115396/is-it-ever-appropriate-to-question-a-downvote/115398#115398), [voting is anonymous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85529/is-down-voting-supposed-to-be-anonymous).  That said, it's within their rights to do so on Stack Exchange.  I don't mind, really.  I assume it has something to do with the CC attribution comment, which I've elaborated on.

Comment: Hmm... These are two different things. There should still be someway to know the *why* of it, than the *who*.

Comment: @Kris: Put the mind-reader request on meta, and I'll upvote it =)

Comment: Wonder if I have to first post "what is a mind-reader request" to know. Honest.

Comment: @Kris: Sorry, I meant the interface between SE and someone's mind; basically, knowing the why is akin to reading minds, who knows?  We know why one *should* downvote something, but that doesn't mean that people *do* for those reasons.  That's just the Interwebs for you.

Comment: Oh well, I did think it was. It would be nice to provide something like you could sign off your comment as *the down voter* [for display only]. SE sure can devise a method to effect this kind of a facility.

Comment: I don't see how SE could claim any intellectual property on your reputation. Copyright definitely applies to the code that computes it, copyright applies to the list of everybody's reputation in some jurisdictions, and in some jurisdictions they might be able to apply for a patent covering the algorithm in context, but how does copyright apply to one reputation value?

Comment: @Gilles Intellectual property rights can be claimed on the *output* of a process as well as the *process itself*.

Comment: @casperOne I'm pretty sure that's impossible in my jurisdiction (it is possible for a patent, but here we're talking about copyrighy). Admittedly my jurisdiction isn't SE's. What in US law can make SE's copyright (on what?) apply to a reputation value? PS Let's move this to chat. [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)?