# Search only content I have voted on

Tags: support, search

Normally I can put in a search like this

```
javascript
```

However, what if I want to restrict the results to only questions and answers that I have voted on? Is this possible?

Comment: No, this is not currently possible.

Comment: Some background http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85539/158100

Comment: The best you can do is go through your votes tab in your profile.