# Can I see -1 reputation in downvoter's reputation tab?

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I downvote an answer, is the lost reputation visible to others in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97445/if-i-downvote-an-answer-is-the-lost-reputation-visible-to-others-in-my-profile)
>   [Revealing voting patterns - new trend?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83548/revealing-voting-patterns-new-trend)

I have to sub-questions:

- Can I see -1 reputation in downvoter's reputation tab when he downvoted my answer/question?
- Can I see -1 reputation in downvoter's reputation tab when he downvoted foreign answer/question?

I think we can't, because everybody says that voting is anonymous

Comment: Have a look now, I'll retract when you're done.

Comment: @shanethehat: no, I do not see it. so first question is answered. and second?

Comment: It hasn't taken any off me, is that how it works on meta?

Comment: @shanethehat: whoops, it's question. It's free to downvote on questions without loss. Everywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the downvotes but you can't see *who* cast the downvotes.

---

Earlier, there was a discussion on [this and how this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97445/if-i-downvote-an-answer-is-the-lost-reputation-visible-to-others-in-my-profile) could be used to [find out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83548/revealing-voting-patterns-new-trend) how has (down)voted whom, but has been fixed since.

Some later time, a bug could reveal downvotes when the reputation report pre-expanded some details. Even then it was not possible to be sure who cast the downvotes, but in the example below, given the total of reputation change of +9, and two received upvotes yielding +10, one could see you downvoted *some* answer. But not which answer:

[image: voting graph]

This has been [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83548/revealing-voting-patterns-new-trend/85546#85546) too.

Comment: well but when you downvote my answer - will I see that you downoted it in your reputation tab (that you have lost 1 rep)?

Comment: dwonvote this & I'll let you know.

Comment: okay, done. what about now ?........

Comment: updated @genesis

Comment: yep, see that:) So you see that I downvoted but you are not sure if it was on your answer. good :) Will keep my downvote for that hour. After that please remember me

Comment: So what about now?

Comment: @Arjan: yes I did.

Comment: @Arjan: it does, ( I received 10 without downvote, so Sathya see that I downvoted but he CAN't be sure if it was to my answer)

Comment: Yes, that's the one @Arjan thanks!

Comment: btw @genesis you can take back the downvote now :P

Comment: @Sathya: yup I was not able to do so before due to vote lock :) Thanks for editing

Comment: I think showing the total of 9 rather than 10, is a bug, given [Nick's statement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83548/revealing-voting-patterns-new-trend/85546#85546) *will not see any indication of downvotes, either in the detailed list or in the day totals*.

Comment: It seems this has been fixed, @genesis: [my reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/84237/arjan?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_time) as I see it [is 1 less than what is publicly visible](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tsv2Y.png).

Comment: @Arjan: so it means nobody know that you downvoted?

Comment: @genesis, indeed, unless someone keeps track of your total reputation score. (On the other hand: there's no confirmation that the screenshot in Sathya's answer was a temporary glitch or bug, nor that is has been fixed. Maybe one can never be sure others cannot tell *some day*...)

Comment: (And if it's confirmed that it's no longer visible, like by *not* seeing any -1 at [my June 17th](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/84237/arjan?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_time) reputation, then I guess the answer needs to be revised a bit?)

Comment: Oh, @genesis-φ, [some regression again](http://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Hlx.png), so folks can (sometimes) see that you downvoted *someone*. Still [a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83548/revealing-voting-patterns-new-trend/85546#85546), I assume.

Comment: @Arjan: yes, I was looking on that before few minutes, too

Comment: @genesis-φ, the bug was solved now, according to [Nick's comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83548/revealing-voting-patterns-new-trend/85546#85546).