# Mobile site exposes downvote data on user rep page

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, down-votes, mobile-web

It seems that the mobile version of Stack Overflow displays downvotes that a user has made, with the time and a link to the downvoted post, on the user's rep page when another person views it. In other words, the mobile rep page does not hide downvote information from onlookers, [unlike the full site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97445/if-i-downvote-an-answer-is-the-lost-reputation-visible-to-others-in-my-profile), and [contrary to established norms about voting anonymity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/allow-users-to-leave-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting).

[image: Another user's rep page]

(Another user's page -- identifying info excised.)

Eeek!

Comment: Investigating...

Comment: Aaaaarggggh!!!! I got used to this feature! I was wondering why it stopped working!

Comment: @Tomas: You were "using" this?! To do what? Voting information isn't supposed to be public.

Comment: @Josh: e.g. to see that particular person unnecessarily downvoted [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804166/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-a-sort-order-on-a-group-of-records-in-a-d/6804302#6804302) just because he did't understood it, just because he didn't like it, without having any argument. He didn't even read the question well. BTW, the information was public until your feature-report, and I considered it so...

Comment: @Tomas: This was a bug. It's deliberately never been public on the full version of the site. It's considered secret information -- it's even cleansed from the public data dumps -- and acting on it is not the way the site is supposed to work. Look at some of the questions in this search: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=see+who+downvoted, particularly [this answer by Diago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer/27535#27535). Take this up with the devs if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

.....yyeeeeeessss.... one can see how that might be considered a bad thing. Deploying currently...