# Why can't a user freeze all upcoming answers and comments to his on-hold questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions, down-votes

I gain random traffic that is downvotes because of the number of questions asked in my account. Note that I have not asked all questions myself, since the admins made a mistake 2008-2008 by combining my account to my brother and sister accounts.

In short, I do not want any answer or upvote or downvote to many of my questions caused by confusion.

One other way is to make the **names of downvoters and upvoters public** such that I can start to flag those users if necessary.

Comment: The last part of your question has been asked and rejected over and over again. Voting is anonymous. It always has been anonymous, it always will be anonymous. Comments are *encouraged* but *not required* when you downvote.

Comment: Well... not _[always](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101014/131713)_....

Comment: "*Mostly* always." -Miracle Max

Comment: It sounds like the _problem_ isn't that people are anonymously downvoting, but that you claim your account is associated with questions/answers which aren't your own.  You may want to elaborate on that part instead.

Comment: @David It is really annoying that Jeff and other boys can make such mistakes. There is a lot that a lot of questions in my account not asked by me. It would take me hours to go them through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If some accounts were incorrectly merged, then it was **probably** a result of noticeable cross-voting hinting that they were, in fact, a single user trying to "game" the system. But: if a **very small** number of questions from this are causing you big problems then *as a gesture of goodwill*, let me know which and I will disassociate them from your account. To be clear - I really mean "I can count them without taking my socks off" here...

Just *please* stop editing them all!

Re the actual *question(s)* here:

> Why user cannot freeze all upcoming answers and comments to his old questions?

because *in general*, that is part of an important feedback loop, that is intended to help you understand the question, etc.

> One other way is to make the names of downvoters and upvoters public such that I can start to flag those users if necessary.

That is not going to happen. If they downvote a poorly written question, then... don't write poorly written questions! Downvotes don't *actually* sting very much.

Comment: Please, tell me how to contact you in private. I do not want distract many people by such requests.

Comment: Lol, you are probably in some irssi -channel, but which server, freenode?

Comment: I am not on any irssi. I'm available here, or my email is in my profile.