# Can anybody see my voting history?

Tags: support, voting, moderators

Can anybody (excluding me, of course) see my voting history?

Do moderators have access to that?

Comment: In short, no moderator can see your votes. Only developers or the community team can check it out in case of serious voting fraud.

Comment: Please search at least once before asking any question. Please.

Comment: But I searched !

Comment: Seems not. See Nick Craver's answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85546/225020

Comment: Even the "Ask a question" page [seems to link to the duplicate](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WVuyN.png), solely based on your title. Next time, please scroll down a bit. Thanks.

Comment: You can _say_ you searched all you like, but you also have to read the information the system is putting in front of you. When you were composing this question, there is a section called **Questions that may already have your answer** that shows possible duplicate questions. Based on the title you entered here, it **_did show you suggestions that include an answer to this question_**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, moderators cannot see your exact voting history.

For technically reasons it is of course possible for the SE staff to retrieve this data, but my understanding is that they don't do this without good reason.

It is, however, possible for moderators to see some statistics about your votes. For example they are able to see when you have certain patterns of voting for specific users. These measures are for detecting fraudulent voting patterns. Which posts specifically have been voted on is unavailable.