# What imgur domains/sub-domains need to be unblocked to allow images to show

Tags: support, images, imgur

As I have seen in other posts, i.stack.imgur.com is blocked by numerous companies' firewalls including my own. I have started the process to get the restriction lifted but to increase the likelihood of it being granted, have only requested that i.stack.imgur.com be unblocked.

Staying within the context of SO, imgur and the hosting arrangement SO has with them, are there any other sub-domains/domains that I should be requesting be unblocked? i.e. p.stack.imgur.com or *.stack.imgur.com?

I'm not sure if images can still be embedded/hotlinked in posts from other image hosts or not but if they can I'm not interested in unblocking those hosts, just the addresses used by SO for imgur.

Cheers :)

Comment: Unblocking the parent domain `imgur.com` should work just fine. :)

Comment: Yes but I can guarantee that that request would be denied due to the .... colourful content found elsewhere on imgur :) Restricting it to the domains used exclusively by stack overflow makes it much more likely to happen!

Comment: OK, so I'm pretty sure `i.stack.imgur.com` is enough, don't think they plan to use any other letter or naming.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard, if you add that as an answer then I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: It's answered nicely [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209167/152859), but I'm not sure if closing this one as duplicate of the other is correct. Anyway adding answer here will be redundant in my opinion. :)

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't see that link when searching for potential duplicates, it's probably the most clear-cut in terms of answering my question but I guess I just thought that a Q: "What do I need to unblock?" A:"It's this...." question needed to exist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shadow Wizard says in his comment, `i.stack.imgur.com` is enough. I've had the restriction on this lifted and I can now see images in SO posts. I've also checked that stack.imgur.com and imgur.com are both still blocked but do not impact on the ability to see images on SO.