# Pictures appear blank across Stack Exchange networks and dropdown

Tags: bug, images, profile-picture

I navigate through *Edit Profile & Settings* > *Change picture* > *Upload a new picture* > Drag and drop my image or imgur URL > select *Add picture*.

My image now appears on the top-right and under *Public information*.

However, clicking *Change picture* again, from the dropdown, I can see the image is displaying the broken icon, because it is trying to show "https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s8ST.jpg?s=128&g=1" (doesn't load), rather than "https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s8ST.jpg" (loads fine).

[image: fine_fine_broken]

Further, when I hit either *Save...* buttons at the bottom, which display *Your profile has been saved successfully*, when I `Ctrl+Shift+R`, the images appear blank in all my Stack Exchange networks.

[image]

This happens in several browsers (Chrome, Canary, FirefoxDev - current versions), in which I presume more.

I get the same behaviour trying in Stack Exchange Meta, Cognitive Sciences beta,  so presume the same for more networks.

I note, viewing my EXIF data on verexif.com gives *There is no thumbnail*. I feel this could be a possible cause, but likely not. I even tried to [generate an EXIF thumbnail](https://superuser.com/q/220074/184249) to see, but the suggestions didn't work for me.

I have never experienced this behaviour before until now.

I have read [Cannot see pictures on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64402/323062), but imgur doesn't appear to be blocked, plus this doesn't relate solely to Stack Overflow, but all Stack Exchange networks.

If you can see the above 2 screenshots, the it appears not to be an issue with the imgur uploader.

Comment: I can't see your ava either. I do think the imgur issues are linked.

Comment: I can't see your avatar. But I didn't noticed this issue with any other account. Try with a different picture. one with small size

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. All the issues mentioned appear fixed as of now.